# how to modify gradle dependencies react native

Tags: react-native, gradle, dependencies, customization

I am trying to adapt a react native audio player for my custom requirements. I have chosen to adapt [react-native-track-player example](https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/tree/main/example).

I have made modifications to load custom tracks list, however I need to make lower level modification so that playback stops after the audio file is played. I have checked it uses exoplayer gradle dependency.

What would be the steps to follow to download Exoplayer source code and load it from react native?